# Loading an xml file with different view per viewmodel?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

There are two things i want to do with MVVMLight but I don't know where to start.

- Serialise an XML file as a viewmodel or use as a datasource

Would you recommend a different format (i can change at this point), I can't find any tutorials for mvvmlight relating to setting up a datasource initially.

- Use a different layout depending on a particular type of record in the xml file

i'm considering using switch statements to hide/show and reorganise everything programmatically but it doesn't seem right.

I currently use linq to read into a model, but without using MVVMlight (will this still work with MVVM?)

```
public IEnumerable<Quiz.Question> LoadQuestions()
{

        XDocument questionData = XDocument.Load("questions.xml");

        var data = from query in questionData.Descendants("question")
                   select new Quiz.Question
                   {
                       QuestionTitle = (string)query.Attribute("title"),
                       QuestionText = query.Element("text") != null ? query.Element("text").Value.Trim() : string.Empty,
                       QuestionImage = query.Element("image") != null ? query.Element("image").Attribute("src").Value : string.Empty
                   };

        var shuffledData = Enumerable.Shuffle<Quiz.Question>(data);

        return shuffledData;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "datasource"?

Comment: mvvmlight doesn't have anything to do with file formats. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I would like an xml file serialised into a model, if there's a better data format to use then I will use that.

Comment: @Matt I mean loading an xml into a model.

Comment: i've this example http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72/ using XDocument.load how do I do that with mvvmlight?

Answer (score 1):

The format you store you data in and the number of files you use will depend on the data and how it's used within the application.

You need to find the balance in: serialization and deserialization performance/speed, ease of working with the data, size of files, number of files (and management of files), and ability to use external libraries.

When it comes to file foramts and serialization, binary is normally faser than JSON, which is normally faster than XML.

The library you use for the serialization can also affect things greatly. (Hint. if using JSON format data, use JSON.Net rather than DatContractjsonSerializer.)

Again there are no general rules for how to display different data. How you do so will depend on the data, what differs and the archtecture of the app.

If the data is very different you may want to use different pages for the different data.
You could use different usercontrols for each type of data and load the appropriate one within the page.
You could use different templates.
Or you could link (bind) the visibility of a UIElement to the data type or whether certain fields are present in the data.

Comment: In my example it's for a quiz app with multiple choice questions, each question can vary in the number of answers available and the position of each button, but there are only so many variations.

Comment: I have updated with a code snippet of what I did without MVVM, but I want the model decoupled as the view will have so many layouts.